# How to abort an insert of multiple rows in a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

With sql Server 2005.
I have declared a trigger that get fired "AFTER INSERT, UPDATE" , in this trigger I'm using a WHILE and a CURSOR to loop on the INSERTED table's rows.
When I find a row that does not sotisfy a specific condition:

I want the trigger to rise an error and do not insert any of the rows that fired the trigger (not even those that already satisfaied my condition).  <--- I don't know how to do this!

Can you tell me how can I rise the error and prevent the insertion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use rollback

```
IF <some condition>
BEGIN
   RAISERROR ('condition doesn't satisfy something', 16, 1)
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what logic you are doing in that cursor loop, but **if at all possible** try to replace the cursor loop with a query:

```
if exists (select PK from INSERTED where .....)
BEGIN
    --from @SQLMenace's answer
    RAISERROR ('condition doesn't satisfy something', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END
```

a cursor in a trigger gives me a bad feeling: locking, blocking, and slow come to mind...

Comment: Agreed, I am battling production issues right now caused by a cursor loop within a trigger that calls a stored procedure.  We've made it less serious by fixing the indexing, but the only true way out seems to be simply not looping in a trigger.