# How do you to stop and store none duplicate error message in a database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Hello i'm trying to do a report and figure out a way to capture distinct error messages from being stored in a 
database however i would like to store each distinct error message for later use.

Any help would be great

Thank you in advance.

I have pages that store exceptions if any of the code fails.

Even though the tables get dropped once a week, i would like a way to not do an insert unless it is a queue error. If there is a duplicate match 
or something similary to the error however on a different page.

For example,

there is a value in the table called errorMessage

one row can have www.test.com/default.aspx?option=2

throwing a sql error

second row can have the same message but different option values.

Is there a way to have 1 record and have a count to that one record

For example

www.test.com/default.aspx?option=2 count = 2

this way i can reduce the amount of error messages being stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I understand your question right. Here would be my solution.

Having a table named "ErrorMessages" that consist of two columns,"ErrorMessage" and "ErrorCount"

My sql would be the following which would increment the errorcount if it already exists other wise it will update it:

```
 DECLARE @ErrorMessage as nvarchar(4000)
 SET @ErrorMessage = "This is my error message"
 IF EXISTS(SELECT ErrorMessage FROM ErrorMessages WHERE ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage)
      UPDATE ErrorMessages SET ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1 WHERE ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage
 ELSE
      INSERT ErrorMessages (ErrorMessage, ErrorCount) VALUES (@ErrorMessage, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was also hoping to match any possible error id's in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing an INSERT command to store every error, I would call a stored procedure that checks to see if that error message is already in the table, (using a SELECT command to get the ID of any matching row).  If it finds one, then do an UPDATE.  If not, do an INSERT.

The benefit to using a stored procedure is that will be more efficient, by only requiring 1 round trip to the DB.

One other option, which is more complicated and maybe a little creepy, would be to use a trigger (BEFORE INSERT).  Compare the statement in the "inserted" table to see if it matches another row in the table and then you could skip the insert (ROLLBACK TRANSACTION) and do an update instead.  If you are interested in the syntax, look at this SO example.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/794592/283895