# how to restrict insert statement using triggers in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have table named Employee and I need to restrict the insert statements after 4 PM till 8 AM
can anybody help me out with this

```
create trigger ti_account

on Employee

for insert
as

IF (DATEPART(hh,getdate() )not between 8 and 15) 
begin
    print('You cant insert rows  now')
END
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/794084/575376

Comment: can you not stop it at a higher level than actually at the point of insert? please provide more information about the application that performs these updates and why you want to prevent the inserts. it will help you get a better solution.

Comment: we have an exam going on right now and they have asked particularly to stop the insertions during that period of time using triggers

Comment: **IS THIS AN EXAM QUESTION?** I don't understand the relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to stop the insert, you'll also need to rollback. You statement as it is, will just print out the message, but continue with the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
create trigger ti_account

on Employee

INSTEAD OF insert

as

IF (DATEPART(hh,getdate() )not between 8 and 15) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Employee (...) VALUES (inserted.col1, inserted.col2....)
END
```

Mind I detest triggers with a passion and it's FAR better to intercept at source or by invoking a stored proc that does this logic for you as Tanner eluded to.